# get vs put http request object

Tags: django, http

I have some common question about http get vs post,It would be great if someone can clarify with examples...

Examples:-

Here is my view

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'request.post=', request.POST
        print 'request.get=', request.GET
        print 'request.method=', request.META.get('REQUEST_METHOD')
        if 'q' in request.GET:
            message = 'You searched for :%r' % request.POST['q']
        else:
            message = 'You submitted an empty form'
        return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'message': message})
    return render(request, 'search_form.html')
```

search_form.html

```
<body>
    {% if message %}
        <div> {{ message }} </div>
    {% else %}
        <form action="/polls/search/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

1. Will POST request used only with the HTML forms? If not, what are the other ways to do it?
2. Any request without a form is always a GET request?
3. How to handle GET and POST using a form..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Will POST request used only with the HTML forms? If not, what are the
>   other ways to do it?

You can post json or xml too. For example, Jquery uses ajax post of json or xml data type

> Any request without a form is always a GET request?

There are 4 types of http methods, GET,POST, DELETE and PUT. Depending on how you want to use it, you can use any of them.

An article more on this. http://bradley-holt.com/2009/07/html-5-http-methods-rest/

.

Comment: In the above code I changed the POST to GET the url changes to this....http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=j1WIqLduWMzCFJ3fCEwWnH5Q3vzkrava&q=test...so, in forms only POST is permitted?

Comment: By forms do you mean html forms? html forms per se have nothing to do with the type of HTTP method you want to use.

Comment: Yes, html forms..What happens in the above..why the GET does not work as POST..?

Comment: The POST is declared part of HTML forms?